# How to set up Apache Tomcat Server to accept all subdomain

Tags: java, tomcat, web

I am hosting my java web project on a personal server. I am trying to create a subdomain with this pattern: *.mydomainname.com.

But when i try to access test.mydomainname.com it redirects me to tomcat admin panel. is there any way to implement this?

Comment: Did you try it? What happend?

Comment: @Stefan sorry, it seems like my question got autocorrected or reviewed making the meaning of my question changes. I've edited the question.

yes i've tried it, what happened was i got redirected to apache tomcat admin panel.